# Convert List<Byte> with hex values to decimal

Tags: c#, .net

I've a List with either 1, 2 or 4 hex values saved as decimal values. I want to convert them into **one** decimal number.

*Example:*

`List<Byte>` values: 1 and 95 (= 0x01, 0x5F)

I want to convert the list into one decimal number:
0x015F = 351

How can I do that?

Comment: You need the output as `015F` string or 351 in decimal?

Answer (score 4):

```
var result = 0;
var i = 0;
foreach (var val in values) 
{
    result = (result << i) + (int)val;
    i += 8;
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to generalize this solution. In case I don't know how many values I want to convert. For example: 0x00 0x20 0x00 0x30 0x10 0x24

Comment: It uses `int` (`System.Int32`), so will not work for a `List<byte>` with more than four entries. You can use `long`/`ulong`, or `BigInteger`, instead of `int`, for the `result` variable. Just change the first line to `BigInteger result = 0;`.

Answer (score 0):

Modern, LINQ-based way (old-fashined C-programmers can turn in one's grave):

```
List<Byte> list = new List<byte>() { 0x01, 0x5F };
var output = list.Select(x => (int)x)
                 .Reverse()
                 .Aggregate((x, y) => (int)0x100 * y + (int)x);
```

Answer (score 0):

With `BitConverter` class, you can do:

```
  var values = new List<byte> { 0x01, 0x5F, };

  byte[] arr = new byte[4];
  for (int i = 0; i < values.Count; ++i)
    arr[values.Count - 1 - i] = values[i];
  int result = BitConverter.ToInt32(arr, 0);
```

You fill the array `arr` backwards from the middle, as seen.

If the numbers can be greater (i.e. the `List<>` can be up to 8 bytes long), use `ulong` (never negative), for example:

```
  var values = new List<byte> { 0x01, 0x5F, };

  byte[] arr = new byte[8];
  for (int i = 0; i < values.Count; ++i)
    arr[values.Count - 1 - i] = values[i];
  ulong result = BitConverter.ToUInt64(arr, 0);
```

If the `List<>` can be arbitrarily long, use `new BigInteger(arr)` (requires csproj reference to `System.Numerics.dll` assembly).